# Rust bindings for Python using pyo3

Tags: python, rust, binding, pyo3

I am trying to generate Rust bindings for Python. Here is a simple example:

```
  use pyo3::prelude::*;
  
  struct MyClass<T> {
     num: T,
  }
  
  impl<T> MyClass<T> {
     fn new(num: T) -> Self {
       MyClass { num }
     }
  }
  
  /// A Python module implemented in Rust.
  #[pymodule]
  fn string_sum(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_class::<MyClass<i32>>()?;
      Ok(())
  }
```

How can I generate bindings for generic Rust types?

Comment: Trying to use generics across languages usually goes poorly. Do you know what types you want to support, or at least how you want to use it from the Python side?

Comment: @kmdreko I'd like to restrict types to floats and integers, at least for now.